# jQuery difference between live() and ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, ready

What is the exact difference between `live()` and `ready()`?

---

Edit: found that [`die()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/die) is the opposite of `live()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`.ready()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready) lets you register a callback that fires when the DOM is ready - this is similar to using `window.onload` but fires earlier (and you can register more than one callback).

[`.live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) lets you register a callback to a range of events based on a selector, which continually monitors the DOM and will register itself to new nodes that are added.

Comment: Thanks, so ready() isn't fired again when the DOM is maniplulated again?

Comment: @powtac, no it's not. Only when the DOM initially loads.

Answer (score 1):

live is used for attaching events to a current selector and all future matching selectors.

ready binds a function to be executed whenever the DOM is ready to be traversed and manipulated

Comment: that live isn't supported for all events is probably the main reason

Comment: Which elements are not suported by live() ? document?

Comment: i think you're not thinking of this properly.  YOu want to use ready to know when the DOM is ready for manipulation.  Your live() usage will be inside the ready call.  They're not really comparable
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live lists all supported elements

Comment: submit and change aren't supported with live() at the moment, although they're on the roadmap for 1.4

Answer (score 1):

`ready()` fires once after the DOM has finished loading and is ready to be traversed and manipulated. Basically a replacement for the old trustworthy `onload` event on `window` (similar but not identical)

With `live()` you specify a selector and jQuery then attaches the function you specify as second argument to all elements matched now and in future (add to to DOM dynamically) for the event specified as first argument