# jQuery Show/Hide not working after postback

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, postback

I am having issues after the postback displaying a hidden div using jQuery. It was suggested that I store the visibility value in a hidden field, but I'm having a few issues. Heres the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $("goBtn").click(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
    return false;
});  
</script>

<div class="create">
            <asp:TextBox ID="createTextbox" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="22px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="goBtn" ImageUrl="img/goBtn.gif" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" onclick="createButton_Click"/>
        </div>
 <div class="slidingDiv" runat="server">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="IsCreatePostbackVisible" runat="server" Visible="False" value="false"/>
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
        </div>
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void createButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string randAlias = Base62Random();
        string aliasInput = createTextbox.Text;
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime endDate = (DateTime.Now.AddYears(5));
        string UserID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
        string aliasType = "alias";
        if (aliasInput == "")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('You must enter a valid URL')</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Literal1.Text = "<a href=http://go/" + randAlias + ">go/" + randAlias;
        }


        using (DataClasses1DataContext dc1 = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            tblData tblData = new tblData();
            tblData.ALIAS_ID = randAlias;
            tblData.URL = aliasInput;
            tblData.START = date;
            tblData.END = endDate;
            tblData.USER = UserID;
            tblData.TYPE = aliasType;
            dc1.tblDatas.InsertOnSubmit(tblData);
            dc1.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the event set to `goBtn` is not working ? if yes,  set a `#` because is an `id`

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour after adding #. It seems that after the post back the div is being rehidden via $(".slidingDiv").hide();

Comment: any of this html elements are created in a callback action ?

Comment: Here is a similiar issue >> http://forums.asp.net/t/1527207.aspx/1

Comment: After buttonClick, the generated Base62 string is written to the literal, but the slidingDiv remains hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I ended up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $("#goBtn").click(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    })
    if (isPostBack){$(".slidingDiv").show();}
});  
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "IsPostBack", "var isPostBack = true;", true);}
        else 
        {ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "IsPostBack", "var isPostBack = false;", true);}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to 're-register' the click event to your button.

I have had similar issues in the past with hiding and postbacks.

If you define a function:

```
 function ClickListener() {
    $("#goBtn").click(function () {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
            ClickListener();
        });
    }
```

Then hopefully it will work more than once.

Edit: I've also encountered similar problems where changing document.ready() to document.live() has solved the problem. See here: [jQuery difference between live() and ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772863/jquery-difference-between-live-and-ready)

Comment: Switching to live() did not work and threw a jQuery error. The div was no longer hidden as well.

Webpage error details User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Timestamp: Tue, 6 Nov 2012 17:00:35 UTC Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object Line: 2764 Char: 3 Code: 0 URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js