# .hide() not working after dialog postaback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I'm having a problem with a jQuery dialog that is probably right in front of me but I can't figure out...

The dialog works fine. It shows the fields and sends the information and, if it's the case, brings back the validation message. My problem is that when I initialize it, I tell it to hide a div inside of if, and it does. On open the div is not there, but if I try to send the information and it brings back the validation message, it shows the div.

Here is the js that calls the dialog:

```
$(function () {
$('.openDialog').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: { idUsuario: $('#idUsuario').val() },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result').html(result).dialog('open');
            $('#formButtom').hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$('#result').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: { effect: "drop", direction: "up" },
    dialogClass: "dialog",
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    position: "center",
    buttons: {
        "Confirmar": function () {
            $("form").submit();
        },
        "Cancelar":function () { $('#result').dialog('close'); }            
    }        
});    
});
 function dialogSucces(result) {
if (result.cadastro) {
    $('#result').dialog('close');        
    window.location.href = '/usuario/index';
} else {
    $('#result').html(result);
}
}
```

and here is the html:

```
<form id="createUsuarioForm">
    Nome
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, String.Empty, new { @class = "text-error"})
        </div>
    <br />
    E-mail / Login
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Login)<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login, String.Empty, new { @class = "text-error"})
        </div>
    <br />
    <div id="formButtom" class="row demo-row">
        <div class="span2">
            <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancelar", "Index", "Usuario", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've seen this post: [jQuery Show/Hide not working after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255420/jquery-show-hide-not-working-after-postback) and tried doing this in the function, but it didn't work:

```
$(function () {
$('.openDialog').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: { idUsuario: $('#idUsuario').val() },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result').html(result).dialog('open');
            $('#formButtom').hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
    if (this.isPostback) { $('#formButtom').hide(); };
});
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show how your `dialogSuccess` function runs, but I suppose it executes in case of form fault also. If that is, you should to add a line into your `if else` statement there. Like this:

```
function dialogSucces(result) {
  if (result.cadastro) {
    $('#result').dialog('close');        
    window.location.href = '/usuario/index';
  } else {
    $('#result').html(result);
    $('#formButtom').hide(); // once defected form rendered again,
                             // div hide directive should be launched again too
  }
}
```